# Comparing characters in a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to compare following chars in a string and if they're equal, raise the counter. 
With my example code I always get TypErrors related to line 6.
Do you know where's the problem?

Thank you!

```
def func(text):
    counter = 0
    text_l = text.lower()

    for i in text_l:
        if text_l[i+1] == text_l[i]:
            print(text_l[i+1], text_l[i])
            counter += 1

    return counter
```

Comment: `for i in text_l:` iterates over _individual characters_, so that on each iteration `type(i) == str`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i` is *not* an index. Your `for` will iterate over the elements directly, so `i` at any point of time is a *character*, not an *integer*. Use the `range` function if you want the indices:

```
for i in range(len(text_l) - 1): # i is the current index
    if text_l[i + 1] == text_l[i]:
```

You can also use `enumerate`:

```
for i, c in enumerate(text_l[:-1]): # i is the current index, c is the current char
    if text_l[i + 1] == c:
```

In either case, you'll want to iterate until the penultimate character because, you'll hit an `IndexError` on the last iteration with `i + 1` as `i + 1` is out of bounds for the last character.

Comment: There's a bug in this code as `i + 1` will get out of bounds.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: Haha, so easy. Thanks!